# select option is not matching mouse select

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

I'm having a problem with my select.
When i mouse over the options to select an item, it works with the first few, but the feather down you go on the list, the more offset the selection gets.

As you can see here, it works fine. The dot is where the mouse is at.
[image]

And as you can see here, the mouse is so offset so its selecting another item, then the one i want to select

[image]

I'm using this JQuery plugin for the select so I'm able to search in it:
http://www.jque.re/plugins/forms-controls/searchabledropdown/

My question is, how can i fix something like this? I've been trying with some `line-height`, `height` etc etc and i can't seem to get it done.

**EDIT:** [Here's a JSFiddle with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/6qwj0xa4/2/)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you please post your code that you have so far?

Comment: Oh yes ofc. Sorry forgot all about that. I'll make a JSFiddle, and update the question

Comment: Don't forget to add code for a minimal repro to the question as well (or use a Stack Snippet), to prevent link rot from rendering this question useless to future visitors.

Comment: @Jeroen - as i said to Kiran i simply forgot to give the code, i know it's needed so you can see what im doing, or how far i've come etc. I have updated the question now, with a link :-)

Comment: @ Patrick R: your filddle is not showing the problem that you are asking. please add required css, html code, scripts, external files etc that will show your problem.

Comment: @kiran - I can't seem to get the problem in jsfiddle. Don't know why. Not even the search function are working as it should. So it might be hard to show you the problem as i see it. I can't even link you the site where i have the problem, since the an internal site, and can't be shown to others with another IP then i have. Is there anything else i can try do, to show you the problem? Heres the update :: http://jsfiddle.net/6qwj0xa4/2/

Comment: I read @kiran's comment, but meant to clarify that it's important to add the code ***to the question itself***, to prevent [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) from affecting your question.

Comment: @PatrickR your JSFiddles have some problems. With CSS, you are pointing to *.dropdown_abo* (which is a class), and you should point to *#dropdown_abo* (an ID), since your selectbox has this value as ID attribute, and not CLASS.

Comment: @Jeroen - ahhh like that. Now i see what you mean and get the point. Thanks for adding it, and will do that from now on :-) And chimos - thanks for pointing out the mistake in the jsfiddle :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because of the font-type, font-size and/or padding that you are applying to your select/options. 
You can try disabling CSS styles to debug and find which CSS rule is exactly the problem.

Comment: It was the font. When i set the font to Arial, there was no problem at all. Didn't knew fonts could do this, so thanks a lot